# How to get all fields with common fields in spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have a spring boot application where I have a table called voterAvailableTime. This database has the fields:
Date, startTime,endTime and voterName which is a foreign key. What I want to do know is to use a method to put every uniquename in a array with other names who have the same date,start and endtime. But I have blockade right now I do not know how to start.

I was using jpaRepositories to save and find needed information until now. Could someone give me a starting point maybe?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a hash which combines the Date, startTime, endTime values and use that as the key for a map like:

```
Map<Integer, List<VoterAvailableTimeRecord>>
```

So you iterate all the records, for each calculate the hash value, check if it exists in the map. If so add the record to the array, if not, create the array and add it and put it to the map.

You can get your IDE to generate a hash method for you, it would be something like:

```
public int getHash() {
  final int prime = 31;
  int result = 1;
  result = prime * result + ((Date == null) ? 0 : Date.hashCode());
  result = prime * result + ((startTime == null) ? 0 : startTime.hashCode());
  result = prime * result + ((endTime == null) ? 0 : endTime.hashCode());
  return result;
}
```

Comment: I will try this and report back due to work I could not respond sorry

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply had to do a lot for work so I could not sit on this project. I was now thinking of trying to accomplish the task but I did not know how to start, I did not work that much with hash and map...

Comment: Maps are your friend, and one of the most useful data structures you'll work with. They allow you to associate a key with a value and lookup the values for a given key. They keys and values can be any type.

Comment: A hash in this case it just a way to combine several values into one unique value. Given the same 3 input vales for your dates - it will produce the same output value. 
A simple way to accomplish the same thing would be to concatenate all the 3 date strings together into a long string, so that each combination of the 3 dates you are working with yield a unique 'key' for that combination. But using a hash function as illustrated accomplishes the same thing in a bit more elegant and likely robust fashion.